# WSDL import 'location' attribute -vs- XSD import 'schemaLocation' attribute

Tags: xsd, wsdl, jax-ws, wsimport

What is the relationship between:

- the `import` element in [WSDL](http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/)

  -and-
- the `import` element and in [XML Schema](http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd)

... and in particular the relationship between the `location` attribute of the former and the `schemaLocation` attribute of the latter?

Though I can use a [catalog](http://xerces.apache.org/xml-commons/components/resolver/resolver-article.html#s.catalog.files) file (in a JAX-WS / `wsimport` toolchain) to "override" `schemaLocation` attributes for the `xsd:import` element it seems that I can't do the same for the `location` attributes of the `wsdl:import` statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In both cases, the `import` establishes a relationship between a document (be that WSDL or XSD) and an external resource).

Barring the confusion which surrounded the **wsdl:import**, specifically if it could be used to import XSDs or not (in [the interoperable way](http://www.ws-i.org/profiles/basicprofile-1.1-2004-08-24.html#WSDL_and_Schema_Import) it shouldn't), they're both meant to do the same thing for its own kind, i.e. bring in another WSDL's (in the WSDL case), or another XSD's (in the XSD case) definitions in scope, thus allowing a modular approach to authoring.

The attributes you're referring to are meant to be equivalent, in the same way an `import` in Java more or less matches a `using` in C#.

However, the specifics around each are different if you consider the WSDL 1.1 note: while in XSD the **schemaLocation** attribute is optional for xsd:import (since an import's location may be resolved through its namespace using other means allowed by the spec), the same was not built into the [WSDL 1.1 note](http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl#_document-n) for the **location** attribute.

Also, the XSD spec is explicitly allowing for an override:

`The ·actual value· of the schemaLocation, if present, gives a **hint** as to where a serialization of a ·schema document·...`

If you look for [the same in WSDL 2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl20/#modularize), you will notice that now WSDL supports an **include** in addition to the old **import**, basically following the same semantics relative to the namespace associated with the directive. More so, the use of the location attribute is also consistent to that in the XSD, which in return should foster a catalog-based approach to resolve the "dangling" imports.

To round it up, given the mandatory **location** attribute in WSDL 1.1, it didn't make sense to talk about catalogs or overrides since it was not implied or allowed by the note.