# Referencing xml schema element from other WSDL file

Tags: xml, import, wsdl, ref

I have two WSDL files.
I'm trying to use an element defined in one WSDL type in another WSDL file within a complexType element.

For this, I have included the other WSDL file using an import element (otherfile.wsdl is within the same folder).
Furthermore I set the namespaces and used the ref attribute (plus namespace) to reference the element from the other WSDL file.

However, it complains that elements from the othertest namespace are not referencable from this test.wsdl xml schema.
Does someone know how to solve this problem?

Below you will find the code for the two files:

**test.wsdl**

```
<definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
   xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
   xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/"
   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
   xmlns:tns="http://www.example.com/test/" 
   xmlns:ot="http://www.example.com/othertest/" 
   targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/test/" >

<import namespace="http://www.example.com/othertest/" location="othertest.wsdl"/>

<types>
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/test/">     
        <xsd:element name="ResultElement2">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element ref="ot:othertest_element" /> 
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>      
    </xsd:schema>
</types>

</definitions>
```

**othertest.wsdl**

```
<definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
   xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
   xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" 
   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
   xmlns:tns="http://www.example.com/othertest/" 
   targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/othertest/" >

<types>
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/othertest/">
        <xsd:element name="othertest_element">
            <xsd:simpleType>
                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:int"/>
            </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:element>      
    </xsd:schema>
</types>

</definitions>
```

Comment: Shouldn't the "location" attribute in the import element be "schemaLocation" ?

Comment: I don't think so, because then I get the error that the schemaLocation is not allowed in the import element and that the attribute location must be in a import element

Comment: Ah ok - my mistake. In WSDL it is called "location", in XSD it is "schemaLocation" (ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19284484/wsdl-import-location-attribute-vs-xsd-import-schemalocation-attribute). Can you use <include> instead of <import>? I have this in one of my WSDLs: <include schemaLocation="schemaToInclude.xsd" /> - maybe this will help?

Comment: I can only use include in with the xsd namespace (<xsd:include>), however, this does not solve the problem since I keep the same error. I discovered that I can reference the element within an <message> element, but not within the <types> element. Because I want to use the multiple different elements of othertest.wsdl to define new elements, it is not a solution to reference the elements within the <message> element.

Comment: Does someone else know how I can solve this problem, wihtout redefining the elements of othertest.wsdl in test.wsdl again?

Answer (score 2):

I have a partial solution. It seems that when I define the elements/types within a xsd file instead of a WSDL file and import this file using `<xsd:import namespace="..." schemaLocation="..." />` within the `<xsd:schema>` element of `<types>`, it does not complain about the namespaces. However, as soon as I import a wsdl file again (which got the types and elements wrapped within `<types>`), it start to complain about the namespaces again.

However, a problem still remains that I'm provided with wsdl files and not with xsd files.
Is there a way to reuse elements/types defined in a wsdl file wihtin the `<types>` section of another wsdl file?